# Java loops in a programming game

Tags: java, loops

I am having an issue with my loops in a game that I created. I have a game board that is a 10 x 10 grid. It is a 3 part challenge. The first part asked for 20 random treasures, which I worked out just fine. Then the second part was adding 20 random trolls. The loop(s) I used gave me 20 treasures and 30 trolls. I AM TERRIBLE AT LOOPS. I have to stay along these lines of code and cannot use break (I am new to Java, but these are my profs rules).

```java
private int width = 10;
private int height = 10;
//Create an array to hold buttons in a 10 by 10 grid
private EmptyButton[] buttons = new EmptyButton[width * height];
```

```java
Random random = new Random();
int counter = 0;
//Using a while loop when counter is less than number of treasures still hidden
while (counter < game.getNumberStillHidden()) {
    //Declare insertion variable and set to random to place buttons randomly
    int insertionIndex = random.nextInt(buttons.length);
    //Using conditional if button at index is null
    if (buttons[insertionIndex] == null) {
        //insert a treasure button
        buttons[insertionIndex] = new TreasureButton(game, this);
        //Use an acumulator for the counter to move on
        counter++;
    }
}
while (counter < game.getNumberOfTriesLeft()) {
    Random randomOne = new Random();
    //Declare insertion variable and set to random to place buttons randomly
    int insertionIndex = randomOne.nextInt(buttons.length);
    if (buttons[insertionIndex] == null) {
        //insert a treasure button
        buttons[insertionIndex] = new TrollButton(game, this);
        //Use an acumulator for the counter to move on
        counter++;
    }
}
// Loop to add EmptyButton()'s into remaining null indexes within the button array
for (int index = 0; index < buttons.length; index++) {
    // if the current index is null
    if (buttons[index] == null) {
        //add an EmptyButton() 
        buttons[index] = new EmptyButton(newGame, this);
    }
}
// Loop to add all of the contents of the buttonGrid into the gamePanel
for (int index = 0; index < buttons.length; index++) {
    //add buttons to panel
    gridPanel.add(buttons[index]);
}
```

Comment: 1) You don't reset the counter. As a professional software engineer: Don't reuse the counter unless it makes sense for some reason, it makes your control flow needlessly difficult to understand. 2) "I AM TERRIBLE AT X" That is something to never tell oneself, you might eventually believe it. You have a bug somewhere in your code. Happens very often, to everyone.

Comment: How can you be "terrible at loops"?  "Loops" is not a skill.  A loop is just a basic control structure.  Learning to write programs with loop control structures is just a matter of thinking logically about what your program needs to do.  Basically, learning to "run the code" it in your head".  You just practice, and practice until it becomes easy.

Comment: Thank you guys. I have just been working really long on this program and felt lost. I see now that it was a really unhelpful thing to say. Loops just throw me for a loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you use

```
   while (counter < game.getNumberOfTriesLeft())
```

the value of counter is 20 if you have 20 treasures.
You need to reset counter to 0 or use a different one.

Comment: Thank you Kiko that worked! (And I need to change it to game.getNumberStillHidden() as we have 50 tries and the number of trolls was outrageous. Thank you thank you.